# Setting auto complete shortcuts in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When programming Java in Eclipse, I can type `syso` and press control+space to auto-complete this and get `System.out.println();`. I was wondering if there are settings somewhere in Eclipse to allow me to set other shortcuts of this form. (For instance, I'd like to type `syscur` and have this auto-complete to `System.currentTimeMillis();`.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this here: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Templates`. You can also add a Template View, which you find at `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other` -> Search for Templates.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is called [Code Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-EditorTemplates.htm)