# Ctrl + Space with main or syso templates still requires confirmation

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, shortcut

How do you configure Eclipse to produce `System.out.println()` with `syso` or the main method when typing `main` and then pressing `Ctrl` + `Space` without pressing `Enter` to confirm afterwards? I'm having a problem with this on Eclipse, running Ubuntu 14.04, but I know that it's possible because computers at my University(both Win and Linux machines) did this for me on Eclipse.

When pressing `Ctrl` + `Space`, I get the normal suggestion window. This works, but I would like to find out how to copy the set-up I have at Uni, where pressing `Ctrl` + `Space` after entering `syso` writes the statement automatically.

I hope I've explained this well enough. I didn't manage to find anyone with my problem so I asked this question.

Comment: I teach Java and one of 10 students have the same issue(it annoys me, he doesn't care), just try other version of Eclipse, I have a notion that now they don't improve Eclipse anymore, they just change it.

Comment: Just get used to typing `System.out.println` and `public static void main(String[] args)` in full. It really only takes 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @Yoda I might try that when I've got more time, but I hope there to be an actual solution.

Comment: A more descriptive title would increase this question's visibility.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting auto complete shortcuts in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448039/setting-auto-complete-shortcuts-in-eclipse)

Comment: @immibis I used to do that, but I prefer these shortcuts I've become used to, far more than typing, even though I still have to type the majority of things.

Comment: @kdopen I looked at those, and they didn't fix anything. I only found how to make the suggestions for things. I changed `sysout` to `syso` and it didn't change a thing, and it shouldn't as the problem happens with all of the templates in preferences, where, I still get the window pop-up, not the automatic insertion. So after this, can we please de-flag my question?

Comment: @tourniquet_grab thanks, I didn't even realise I didn't complete my question title. I'll get it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Preferences and go to 'Java > Editor > Content Assist'.

Check the 'Insert single proposals automatically' option.

Comment: Thank you, this does what I wanted. 
Turns out it was already checked, but the name helped me fix the issue. I had Intelligent Java Proposals suggestions also showing up in the default suggestions, therefore I wasn't getting a 'single proposal' which stopped it from automatically inserting it.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. How did you turn off the intelligent Java Proposals suggestions?

Comment: In the left pane of the preferences dialog, click the + to the left of "Content Asist" to open up "Advanced".  in the top list, I unchecked "Java proposals" and it fixed the problem

Answer (score -2):

I know in Netbeans, you can type in

```
sout //then hit tab on your keyboard
```

And the hit the tab button on your keyboard, and it automatically prints out

```
System.out.println("")
```

I'm not sure if this works in Eclipse. You can try it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the effect I'm looking for. 
However, it is what I described above that should work in Eclipse, as I have done this on Eclipse running at my University labs.